# Not able to find Images.xcassets folder in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xcasset

So i want to add Vector images to an iOS app,i'm a newbie in terms of iOS but ive worked on Android Apps,while adding scalable images it seems i have to create a folder named Images.xcassets which i did,but for some reason i'm not able to see the folder at all in the solution,and if i try to add one more folder using the same name,it says the folder already exists

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always right click `Asset Catalogs`, select `add Asset Catalogs`

[image]

then you can find it under `Resources` folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do this on Mac Visual Studio,and i don't anything like this

Comment: @Venky right click `Assets.xcassets` and click `Reveal in finder` , you will find `image.imageset`.